# pie chart and bar graph cannot be displayed simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/canvasjs.min1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload ={
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {
  
                animationEnabled: true,
  legend: {
   verticalAlign: "bottom",
   horizontalAlign: "center"
  },
  theme: "theme1",
  data: [
  {        
   type: "pie",
   indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
   indexLabelFontSize: 20,
   indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
   startAngle:0,
   indexLabelFontColor: "MistyRose",       
   indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey", 
   indexLabelPlacement: "inside", 
   toolTipContent: "{name}: {y}hrs",
   showInLegend: true,
   indexLabel: "#percent%", 
   dataPoints: [
    {  y: 52, name: "Time At Work", legendMarkerType: "triangle"},
    {  y: 44, name: "Time At Home", legendMarkerType: "square"},
    {  y: 12, name: "Time Spent Out", legendMarkerType: "circle"}
   ]
  }
  ]
 });
 chart.render();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
   {
    title:{
     text: "Bar chart"
    },

    data: [
    {
     type: "bar",

     dataPoints: [
     { x: 10, y: 90, label:"Gulam" },
     { x: 20, y: 70, label:"Husain" },
     { x: 30, y: 50, label:"Shubhankar" },
     { x: 40, y: 60, label:"Banana" },
     { x: 50, y: 20, label:"Pineapple" },
     { x: 60, y: 30, label:"Pears" },
     { x: 70, y: 35, label:"Grapes" },
     { x: 80, y: 40, label:"Lychee" },
     { x: 90, y: 30, label:"Jackfruit" }
     ]
    }
    ]
   });

   chart.render();
  }
 </script>

     <!-- panel body -->
     <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
      
     </div>
     
     <!-- panel body -->
     <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>      

</body>
</html>
```

i have put two codes one for pie chart and another for bar graph but those two graphs cannot be displayed simultaneously? why? is there any problem with the code only bar graph is displaying pie chart is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
First add function() after the window.onload = code
Then you don't want two window.onload events, so I combined your two onload scripts to be one as show below.  

   <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function(){

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
                animationEnabled: true,
        legend: {
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
            horizontalAlign: "center"
        },
        theme: "theme1",
        data: [
        {        
            type: "pie",
            indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
            indexLabelFontSize: 20,
            indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
            startAngle:0,
            indexLabelFontColor: "MistyRose",       
            indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey", 
            indexLabelPlacement: "inside", 
            toolTipContent: "{name}: {y}hrs",
            showInLegend: true,
            indexLabel: "#percent%", 
            dataPoints: [
                {  y: 52, name: "Time At Work", legendMarkerType: "triangle"},
                {  y: 44, name: "Time At Home", legendMarkerType: "square"},
                {  y: 12, name: "Time Spent Out", legendMarkerType: "circle"}
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();

    chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
            {
                title:{
                    text: "Bar chart"
            },
                data: [
                {
                    type: "bar",
                    dataPoints: [
                    { x: 10, y: 90, label:"Gulam" },
                    { x: 20, y: 70, label:"Husain" },
                    { x: 30, y: 50, label:"Shubhankar" },
                    { x: 40, y: 60, label:"Banana" },
                    { x: 50, y: 20, label:"Pineapple" },
                    { x: 60, y: 30, label:"Pears" },
                    { x: 70, y: 35, label:"Grapes" },
                    { x: 80, y: 40, label:"Lychee" },
                    { x: 90, y: 30, label:"Jackfruit" }
                    ]
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
   }
</script>

                    <!-- panel body -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="chartContainer" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- panel body -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
                    </div>                      

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One `window.onload` function is overwriting the other.

And in the first instance, `window.onload ={` should be this `window.onload = function() {`.

It would however, be better to structure your page correctly and include the scripts at the bottom of the page. This means you can do away with the onload check altogether:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Graphs and ting</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- panel body -->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height:400px; width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- panel body -->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        legend: {
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          horizontalAlign: "center"
        },
        theme: "theme1",
        data: [{
          type: "pie",
          indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",
          indexLabelFontSize: 20,
          indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
          startAngle:0,
          indexLabelFontColor: "MistyRose",
          indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
          indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
          toolTipContent: "{name}: {y}hrs",
          showInLegend: true,
          indexLabel: "#percent%",
          dataPoints: [
            {  y: 52, name: "Time At Work", legendMarkerType: "triangle"},
            {  y: 44, name: "Time At Home", legendMarkerType: "square"},
            {  y: 12, name: "Time Spent Out", legendMarkerType: "circle"}
          ]
        }]
      });
      chart.render();

      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
        title:{
          text: "Bar chart"
        },
        data: [{
          type: "bar",

          dataPoints: [
            { x: 10, y: 90, label:"Gulam" },
            { x: 20, y: 70, label:"Husain" },
            { x: 30, y: 50, label:"Shubhankar" },
            { x: 40, y: 60, label:"Banana" },
            { x: 50, y: 20, label:"Pineapple" },
            { x: 60, y: 30, label:"Pears" },
            { x: 70, y: 35, label:"Grapes" },
            { x: 80, y: 40, label:"Lychee" },
            { x: 90, y: 30, label:"Jackfruit" }
          ]
        }]
      });
      chart.render();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote answers that you found helpful.